# Search for posts should strip special characters

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search, android-app

Searching for posts with special characters, i.e.: `? ! @ # $ % ^ & * ( )` does not display results as intended.

Example, searching the exact title (which has a question mark) does not display the question when it should:

[image]

Searching without the question mark works:

[image]

Comment: I don't know is strip is the right thing here. I'd probably say it should work like the website search with all the special operators.

Comment: Looks like it's stripping out all special tags, as reported in [this dupe](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192291/searching-for-c-searches-for-c-in-the-android-app) even searching for [C#] doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API for search now works much like the website.  Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks Geoff! Great work!